# How to do simultaneous downloads with Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, automation, download

I am trying to test download time automatically with Selenium/Python.  What I have done manually to test this is to have 5 tabs open and then I click a Download button on one tab and then using Cntrl-Tab move quickly to the next tab click Download, etc.. and time it.

I have gotten to the point of creating the code to have 5 tabs open but when I click on Download in the 1st tab it is waiting for the file to be fully downloaded before I can move to the next tab.  Must the file be fully downloaded before the code can move to the next line?

In order to move to the next tab I have tried both using keystrokes and switching windows handles.  They both work, but they are waiting for the download to be complete, whereas I want all the downloads to be downloading together.

1. Tab 1 - Click Download
2. Move to next tab or switch window handles
3. Tab 2 - Click Download
4. Move to next tab or switch window handles
5. Tab 3 - Click Download
6. Move to next tab or switch window handles
7. Tab 4 - Click Download
8. Move to next tab or switch window handles
9. Tab 5 - Click Download

Isn't there a way to click Download on the following tabs while the prior tabs' downloads are happening?

Would I need to use multi-threading for this?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I think a process pool would be perfect for your case.

Here is the digest

```py
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor

def download_from_tab(tab_num):
    pass

with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    for tab_num in range(number_of_tabs):
       _ = executor.submit(download_from_tab, tab_num)
```

The code above will open a new process for each tab and start downloading things in parallel.

You can find the oficinal documentation here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor

There is also an awesome video that shows step-by-step how to use processes for exactly this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fKl2JW_qrso

Comment: Thanks a lot Arthur for the quick response!  I will look into this!